# Hibernate: mapping two classes to a common third class

Tags: hibernate, mapping, one-to-many

I am searching for the correct mapping of a many-to-one relationship of two classes pointing on a third one.
An example is shown in the image below:

[image]

In words;
a Person has 1..n addresses
a Company has 1..n addresses

I'd like to have a single table for all addresses.
For the moment a uni-directional relation is all I need, but it would be also nice to see how this works with bi-directional relations.

I believe the correct database representation is like in the next image

[image]

But I don't know how to translate this into a hibernat xml file or a java class using hibernate annotations.

This problem has been discussed 5 years ago in the hibernate forum:
"https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=961387"
but I think they found no satisfactory solution.

regards.

Julien

Comment: reading hibernate documentation helps http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a very normal "unidirectional one-to-many with join table" relationship as described in [Chapter 8 of the Hibernate reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/associations.html#assoc-unidirectional-join-12m) and [Chapter 2 of the Annotations reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#d0e1642).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I think i made this unnecessarily complicated and I've overseen this simple solution.
Now it works